# Python: How to make Next button read diffrent files.

Tags: python, button, file-upload

I'am going to make a window with Next button, a Text Widget and Label widget. I want when I klick on Next button will read adiffrent files on Text widget, i mean first click on Nexst will read file_1 in Text widget, and secound click will read file_2, and so on. so can anyone help me, thanks

Comment: You need to explain your problem and what you have tried better.

Comment: I have two files which i want to appear قespectively in Text Widget when i click on Next button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shelf might do it. Try opening the file in shelf, reading it, printing it, then closing it. When the button is hit a variable is incriminated. This variable points to an index in an array which holds the file names. It would then pass the file path to the function like this:

import shelve
I = 0
Paths = array containing file paths

FUNCTION file (path):
   This function opens reads prints and closes the      -  file at path

WHILE True:
   This loop calls the function with args paths[i]
    I++

BTW THAT EAS NOT MEANT TO BE PYTHON CODE BUT JUST A REPRESENTATION

P.S if I have got the wrong end of the stick pls tell me and I will change my awnser